Implement a background task to run every 1-min for periods longer than 6-hours. Android API 35+
tl;dr
How can I implement a background task to run every 1 minute, even in low-power or doze-mode, in Android API 35+, for periods longer than 6 hours?
Details
Requirements

[R1] - A background service must run every 1-minute to call a web-server and update the database. If certain conditions are met, a notification must be shown to the user
[R2] - The periodic check must run until the user stops it (or certain conditions are met). This may be for over 6 hours.
[R3] - The periodic check must run even if the app is in doze mode

Implementation before API 34
The user with an action in the UI starts a Foreground Service with a notification. The Foreground Service starts a background task using Executor which will perform the necessary actions and then sleep for 1 minute.
Implications with API 35
Since API 34, the Foreground Service needs to have a Foreground Service Type. The most relevant seem to be data_sync. However, since API 35, this will be limited to 6-hours max running period, and then it will time out. This does not meet [R2] above. It also appears that data_sync type will be deprecated in future releases.
Alternatives Examined
WorkManager API
As it is documented here,

Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes

This will not meet [R1]
AlarmManager API
When using the AlarmManager, when the device is in low-power mode, the alarms cannot be triggered more frequently than 15-mins. This is also documented here.

Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes.

This again fails requirement [R1]
What is the recommended way to achieve the above in Android API 35+ ?

"What is the recommended way to achieve the above in Android API 35+ ?" -- sell your own hardware with your own custom build of Android on it, where you modify that custom build of Android to allow what you seek. "Implementation before API 34" -- this approach will not work on many Android devices due to manufacturer changes.

@Lefteris, maybe you can try WorkManager with ForegroundService under long running tasks (more than 10 minutes) where your task will be in an infinite loop with delay of 1 minute in loop. https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/how-to/long-running

@dev.tejasb, I think that this approach (although easier to implement than my current implementation), still has the same problem. In the link you shared and more specifically here (https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/how-to/long-running#foreground-service-type) it is mentioned that "Note: Depending on which API level your app is targeting and what kind of work the service is doing, you may be required to declare a foreground service type...".

ofcourse you need to define a service type for a foreground service. after looking into foreground service types, I came accross specialUse service type which I think you need to use as none of the predefined service types work for your use case. https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/fg-service-types#special-use

@dev.tejasb This is true. The only problem which I wanted to avoid (if possible), was that when using the specialUse service type, it is mentioned in the documentation that "...These values and corresponding use cases are reviewed when you submit your app in the Google Play Console". I wanted to be able to avoid a lengthier review process, but so far it seems that this is the only way forward. Thank you for your response though.

@Lefteris because of your use case scenario, you've no other option but to use the specialUse type and for the app time review from the Google Play team will only be more for the first time. once approved, next updates will be faster unless you make heavy changes in the app.

Not a recommendation but possible work arounds.
Use WorkManager API to setup a OneTimeWorkRequest with a Delay of 1 minute.
When that fires do your work and in the work request setup the next OneTimeWorkRequest with a 1 minute delay.
You might want to prune the work queue not to overload it with old jobs.
I've done this but not on API 35+
Or
I've not tired this but a combination approach might be possible, use a Foreground Service combined with a Periodic work request to restart a new Foreground Service every 6 hours.
This approach has other benefits as there are probably various other reasons your Foreground service could stop, checking it's running and starting again could be useful.

if the first approach works then, edge cases should be considered like when an error occurs, restart policy, etc. and for the second approach, I don't think that we can start a foreground service from a worker aside from it's own foreground service for long running tasks.
